# Difficulties of getting raw data

Tags: data-mining, data, open-source

I am trying to obtain raw data for (violent) crime rates of a US/Canadian city (any city would do), but I need the data to be granular and raw. All I could find is either interpretations, summary data or useless editorials. I'm trying to do analysis, and I need day-by-day (detailed-level, granular) data that shows the number of crimes recorded per day. Does anyone have any good sources/suggestions for finding this? Thank you immensely!

Answer (score 1):

I found some sites providing open data.

1. You can find crime data by year, by city in [here](http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/crime-stats).
   Data contains incident number, crime type, date, time, location.
2. [This site](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=crime) also provides crime data.

I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I had seen them both, unfortunately they have one drawback in common: they are summary data, they don't provide day-to-day information, it's rolled up to yearly data. I've even found quarterly, but i need raw data with day granularity - time even.

Comment: @LearnByReading Um.. when I looked into dataset from those sites, incidents are recorded almost day-to-day. Do you find something per incident?

Comment: I searched a few cities and didn't find any, but then I looked for some more major cities and found the exact thing I was looking for (Chicago, IL) for those of you who are also looking. Thank you very much, I'll keep the question open for a couple of days and if nobody else posts an answer, I'll choose yours. Thanks!